# What year/model is it?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I'm very sure that the attached picture is my '55, '56 or '57 Schwinn Traveler. But I've never seen markings like this one has; the striped bands around the frame, the name "Schwinn" in script, and the white pinstriping near the top of the fork. Anyone got an opinion?  Thanks!!

The edge of the picture got cut off, but it is dated, June, 1957.
[image: The edge of the picture got cut off, but it is dated, June, 1957.[1]]

Comment: There aren't really many visible features to date it, other than I haven't seen those hub polishers in about 50 years.

Comment: Could the paint have been customised by someone?   I notice its got a really short headtube for the era.  Back then head tubes were much longer.  Crankwheel has an Ace of Spades motif.  Back wheel seems to have a small IGH ?  Or maybe thats a coaster brake.   Certainly a 1950s roadster, and a loverly bike.

Comment: @criggie good eyesight. I’m spying a classic 2/3 speed shifter on the right handlebar to go with IGH theory

Comment: You seem to already know the model and the exact year is unlikely to make much difference to anything. Also, in those days, I suspect the trend of releasing a slightly different bike each year hadn't really begun.

Comment: Well, that's me in the picture, so I remember a few things.

Comment: The date of printing of the picture is June, 1957, and I got the bike for Christmas (the best Christmas EVER!). I'm assuming the previous Christmas. It had a 3 speed shifter. I had not repainted it at that time.  Today, I found some other pictures on the internet, and I now think it looks like a 1957 Schwinn Racer Deluxe (because of the s/s fenders). What do you think?